# Conditional Expected Value of Birnbaum-Saunders Bivariate

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, integral

Consider $(T{1},T_{2})\sim BVBS(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1},\alpha_{2},\beta_{2}).$ According to item (b) of Theorem 3.1 of Balakrishnan and Kundu (2010) [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X09001122), we have:

\begin{align*}
f_{T_{1}|T_{2}=t_{2}}(t_{1})=&\dfrac{1}{2\alpha_{1}\beta_{1}\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}\Biggl\{\left(\dfrac{\beta_{1}}{t_{1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\dfrac{\beta_{1}}{t_{1}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\Biggl\}\\
\times& \exp{\Biggl\{-\dfrac{1}{2(1-\rho^{2})}\left[\dfrac{1}{\alpha_{1}}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{t_{1}}{\beta_{1}}}-\sqrt{\dfrac{\beta_{1}}{t_{1}}}\right)-\dfrac{\rho}{\alpha_{2}}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{t_{2}}{\beta_{2}}}-\sqrt{\dfrac{\beta_{2}}{t_{2}}}\right)\right]^{2} \Biggl\}}\\
=&\dfrac{A_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}\times \exp{\Biggl\{-\dfrac{1}{2(1-\rho^{2})}\Biggl[a_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})-
\rho a_{t_{2}}(\alpha_{2},\beta_{2})\Biggl]^{2} \Biggl\}}
\end{align*}

on what $A_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})=\dfrac{1}{2\alpha_{1}\beta_{1}}\Biggl\{\left(\dfrac{\beta_{1}}{t_{1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\dfrac{\beta_{1}}{t_{1}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\Biggl\},
\ a_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})=\dfrac{1}{\alpha_{1}}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{t_{1}}{\beta_{1}}}-\sqrt{\dfrac{\beta_{1}}{t_{1}}}\right)$ and 
$a_{t_{2}}(\alpha_{2},\beta_{2})=\dfrac{1}{\alpha_{2}}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{t_{2}}{\beta_{2}}}-\sqrt{\dfrac{\beta_{2}}{t_{2}}}\right).$

I want to find

\begin{align}
E(T_{1}|T_{2}=t_{2})=&{\displaystyle \int \limits_{0}^{+\infty}t_{1}f_{T_{1}|T_{2}=t_{2}}(t_{1})dt_{1} }\\
=&{\displaystyle \int \limits_{0}^{+\infty}t_{1}\dfrac{A_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}\\
\times \exp{\Biggl\{-\dfrac{1}{2(1-\rho^{2})}\Biggl[a_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})-
\rho a_{t_{2}}(\alpha_{2},\beta_{2})\Biggl]^{2} \Biggl\}}dt_{1}}
\end{align}

In trying to solve, I observed that:

$\dfrac{d}{dt_{1}}a_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})=A_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})$ and what if

$z=\dfrac{a_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})-\rho a_{t_{2}}(\alpha_{2},\beta_{2})}{\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}$ we have to $dz=\dfrac{A_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})}{\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}dt_{1}.$

In addition, $z\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}+\rho a_{t_{2}}(\alpha_{2},\beta_{2})=a_{t_{1}}(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1})$ I got

$t_{1}=\beta_{1}\left[\dfrac{\alpha_{1}}{2}\left(z\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}+\rho a_{t_{2}}(\alpha_{2},\beta_{2})\right)+\sqrt{\dfrac{\alpha_{1}^{2}}{4}\left(z\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}+\rho a_{t_{2}}(\alpha_{2},\beta_{2})\right)^{2}+1} \right]^{2}$

Therefore,

\begin{align}
E(T_{1}|T_{2}=t_{2})=&{\displaystyle \int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \beta_{1}\left[\dfrac{\alpha_{1}}{2}\left(z\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}+\rho a_{t_{2}}(\alpha_{2},\beta_{2})\right)\\
+\sqrt{\dfrac{\alpha_{1}^{2}}{4}\left(z\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}+\rho a_{t_{2}}(\alpha_{2},\beta_{2})\right)^{2}+1} \right]^{2} \phi(z)dz}
\end{align}

on what $\phi(\cdot)$ is standard normal density. Can anyone help?